# "Meet with David" - meaning in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

What does "meet with David" mean in this context?
Is it the short form of "Meeting with David"?

I thought the verb "to meet" doesn't require the preposition "with." We use "meet sb," for example:
Sue is going to meet David.

[image: Calendar's excerpt]

Answer (score 2):

*Sue met David* typically means that she became acquainted with him, as when someone first introduced them to one another. *Sue met **with** David* means that the two came together for a discussion, to transact business, etc.  The latter is what conveys the sense of “attended a meeting together.”

On the other hand, something like *Sue met David **for** dinner* means that they had agreed to join up and dine together. And saying that she met him ***in** Paris* or ***at** the museum* is ambiguous; such statements can serve to report either where they became acquainted or where they accomplished an agreed rendezvous-vous.

Comment: All the entries are reminders to herself to do a certain thing on a certain day. It's the verb, not the noun _meeting_.

Comment: Yes, @KateBunting, exactly. In my answer I was merely trying to provide a fuller explanation of the usages of *to meet*.

Comment: The comment was intended for the OP, not a criticism of your answer.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that most British people regard 'meet with' as an Americanism.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  How would a Brit say "He met with the Prime Minister"?

Comment: @TimR - if he encountered the Prime Minister in the street, or at a party, reception, or other kind of gathering, then, he _met the PM_ whether for the first time or not.  If he _had a meeting_, scheduled or impromptu, _with the PM_, then that's how we would talk about it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Looks like the Brits began to avoid "met with" shortly after the US declared  independence. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=met+with&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3